# Calling a javascript function from a global file and return it to append to html

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, generics, handler

[image]I have a global javascript file 'Global.js' with a Global Handler 'GlobalHandler.ashx', 
what i am trying to do is to render some data in the back-end (inside the handler ), than return text data using `context.Response.Write(MyString)`

The question is how to append the data to my html element . 
I looked into the response (200) and the data is there , but i don't know the reason of not appending my text into the html element

I have tried to append them like the classic way `success:function(data){
$(elementID).html(data);}`
But that doesnt work

Here In Global.js

```
function GetProfession(elementID) {
$.ajax({
    url: "/Handlers/GlobalHandler.ashx",
    dataType: "JSON",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    //responseType: ResponseType,
    data: {
        functionName: "GetProfession"
    },
    success: function (data) {
        return $("#" + elementID).html(data);
    }
});
}
```

Here In MyPage.aspx

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        GetProfession("Profession");
    });
```

HERE In the Handler

```
 string functionName = context.Request["functionName"];
        GroupDAO GroupDAO = new GroupDAO();
        if (functionName.Equals("GetProfession"))
        {
            var ListOfGroups = GroupDAO.GetGroups();
            string Builder = "";
            foreach (var group in ListOfGroups)
            {
                Builder+="<option value='" + group.GroupID + "'>" + group.GroupName + "</option>";
            }
            context.Response.Write(Builder);
        }
```

I am expecting to have those options appended to the html element 'Profession'
but this unfortunately it does not happening

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer , i did not recognize the logical reason of such behaviour , 
but the data was not in the success method even if the statuc code was 200 . 
in fact it was in the error: properties of ajax request . 
what i have done is : 
instead of appending the data in success to the html element . 
i did it in the response text 
.

Here is the code before not working :

```
  function GetProfession(elementID) {
$.ajax({
    url: "/Handlers/GlobalHandler.ashx",
    dataType: "JSON",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    //responseType: ResponseType,
    data: {
        functionName: "GetProfession"
    },
    success: function (data) {
        return $("#" + elementID).html(data);
    }
});
}
```

Here is the one that works

```
function GetProfession(elementID) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Handlers/GlobalHandler.ashx",
        dataType: "JSON",
        contentType: "text/html; charset=utf-8",
        //responseType: ResponseType,
        data: {
            functionName: "GetProfession"
        },
        success: function (data, fata, meta) {
        },
        error: function (err) {
            $("#Profession").html(err.responseText);
            //alert(err.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```